# NumberFormatter strange behavior

Tags: swift

I found a strange behavior in Swift's NumberFormatter.

```
func testNumberFormat() {
    let numberFormat = { (number: NSNumber) -> (String?) in
        let formatter: NumberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
        formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
        formatter.roundingMode = .halfUp

        return formatter.string(from: number)
    }

    XCTAssertEqual(numberFormat(Decimal(0.004) as NSNumber)!, "0.00") // OK
    XCTAssertEqual(numberFormat(Decimal(0.005) as NSNumber)!, "0.01") // OK
    XCTAssertEqual(numberFormat(Decimal(10000.004) as NSNumber)!, "10,000.00") // OK
    XCTAssertEqual(numberFormat(Decimal(10000.005) as NSNumber)!, "10,000.01") // NG!
    XCTAssertEqual(numberFormat(Decimal(10000.014) as NSNumber)!, "10,000.01") // OK
    XCTAssertEqual(numberFormat(Decimal(10000.015) as NSNumber)!, "10,000.02") // OK
}
```

The following test is failed.

```
XCTAssertEqual(numberFormat(Decimal(10000.005) as NSNumber)!, "10,000.01")
```

I expect "10,000, 01", but "10,000, 00" was return.
Is my understanding mistaken?

Comment: If you use `Double` it works fine which makes me wonder about some rounding issues with `Decimal` type probably causing that issue.

Comment: `print(Decimal(10000.005) as NSNumber)` prints `10000.004999999997952`, so that would round to `10000.00`.

Comment: See [is floating point math broken](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/1630618)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
print(Decimal(10000.005)) //->10000.004999999997952
```

You know `10000.004999999997952` will be formatted as `10,000.00` with your `numberFormat`.

Binary floating point `Double` cannot represent the precise value of `10000.005`, so the result of `Decimal.init(_: Double)` is hard to predict.

If you want to hold a precise decimal representation in `Decimal`, you should use `Decimal(string:)` instead.

```
print(Decimal(string: "10000.005")!) //->10000.005
print(numberFormat(Decimal(string: "10000.005")! as NSNumber)!) //->10,000.01
```

If you want to convert `Double` to `Decimal` with precisely representing a `print`ed value, you may need some more code.